# Decomposition of int into addition

Tags: python, math

I am having trouble with a problem of mine, and was wondering if you'd have any hints/tips.
Basically, I have a variable (an int) that I want to break into an addition of a given number of terms. And, because it was too simple, these terms must be chosen from an array of possible terms. (Let's assume here there's at least one way to do it, verifications would have been done before)
Allow me to illustrate:

```
var = 12
nbr_terms = 3
possible_terms = [2, 3, 4, 6]
# Function to create
breaker(var, nbr_terms, possible_terms)
```

The `breaker()` function should return (one of) the decomposition.
For example, here it could be `6+3+3` or `4+4+4`.

I have an idea that I think could work, merely it could become extremely resource consuming if the `possible_terms` array was to have a lot of elements. It would be to loop through this array to test every combination possible of the given number of terms, to store every working combination in an other array, and pick one randomly. Besides, as the `nbr_terms` is also a parameter, I wouldn't know how to proceed.

Well, this is my problem, I hope it is understandable! If you have any question, feel free to ask, I'd be happy to help you helping me.

Comment: Use recursion. Subtract the first element from the variable, then try to decompose the result. Keep recursing until the result is smaller than any of the elements in the list.

Comment: If you don't find a solution, try subtracting the next element and then repeat the recursion.